# Python: length calculation matrix vs array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Using the `len()` fct to get the length of an array (int32) seems simple.
But how to get the length of a matrix (float64)/ of one of its dimensions?

Example:

Array of the 8760 hours of a year: 
`f = np.arange(8760).reshape((1,8760))
f_len = len(f[0,:])`

Doing the same for a matrix (1,8760) does not work. Any other approaches (such as `sum(len(x) for x in` and others) failed.
Using `np.shape()` is a good idea. But I need the actual value of one of the dimensions (here '8760' and not '1') for further calculations...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you:

```
f_len = len(f[0])
f_len = f.shape[1]
```